# How to create a project in Ionic v4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to start playing with new Ionic v4. What do I have to do create a new project in it.

I have updated the global install by doing `npm install -g ionic@4.0.0-rc.5`.

So now if I do `ionic -v` I get `4.0.0-rc.5`.

When I create a new project with New cli installed by doing ionic start newproj blank I get the following in my package.json.

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  }`

Note that "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ionic-angular The last version is : "3.9.2"

see [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-angular)

if you needs install ionic-angular 4.0.0 alpha vesrion

```
 npm install ionic-angular@4.0.0-alpha.0
```

Comment: did that. It breaks the app with various errors such as `Module '"E:/v4Demo2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.`

Comment: npm uninstall ionic-angular@3.9.2
then npm install ionic-angular@4.0.0-alpha.0